# Tikz drawing uneven node sizes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the code below, the last node (10) comes out as larger than the others when rendered. How do I stop this from happening?

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
[every node/.minimum size=2cm]
\node (1) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (87.5pt, -150.0pt) {\textcolor{black}{1}};
\node (2) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (112.5pt, -137.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{2}};
\node (3) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (137.5pt, -137.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{3}};
\node (4) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (112.5pt, -162.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{4}};
\node (5) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (137.5pt, -162.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{5}};
\node (6) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (162.5pt, -137.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{6}};
\node (7) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (162.5pt, -162.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{7}};
\node (8) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (187.5pt, -137.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{8}};
\node (9) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (187.5pt, -162.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{9}};
\node (10) [circle, fill=black, draw=black] at (212.5pt, -150.0pt) {\textcolor{black}{10}};
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (1) to  (2);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (1) to  (4);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (4) to  (5);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (2) to  (3);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (4) to  (2);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (5) to  (3);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (3) to  (6);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (5) to  (7);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (8) to  (6);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (7) to  (9);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (8) to  (10);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (9) to  (10);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (7) to  (6);
\draw [line width=0.625, color=black] (9) to  (8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! last node is large because its content is large than in other nodes, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Make the `inner sep` something nonzero of your choice and remove the numbers from the end. `{10}` writes 10 in the node but since you are filling it, no point in writing them. Then initial normal parentheses e.g., `(10)`set the labels already.

Answer (score 3):

Use `[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.2em}]` for example. And what is the point of adding numbers if they will not be visible?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.2em},
    ball/.style={circle, fill=black, draw=black},
    line/.style={line width=0.625, color=black},
    ]
\node (1)  [ball] at (87.5pt, -150.0pt) {\textcolor{black}{1}};
\node (2)  [ball] at (112.5pt, -137.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{2}};
\node (3)  [ball] at (137.5pt, -137.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{3}};
\node (4)  [ball] at (112.5pt, -162.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{4}};
\node (5)  [ball] at (137.5pt, -162.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{5}};
\node (6)  [ball] at (162.5pt, -137.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{6}};
\node (7)  [ball] at (162.5pt, -162.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{7}};
\node (8)  [ball] at (187.5pt, -137.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{8}};
\node (9)  [ball] at (187.5pt, -162.5pt) {\textcolor{black}{9}};
\node (10) [ball] at (212.5pt, -150.0pt) {\textcolor{black}{10}};
\draw [line] (1) to  (2);
\draw [line] (1) to  (4);
\draw [line] (4) to  (5);
\draw [line] (2) to  (3);
\draw [line] (4) to  (2);
\draw [line] (5) to  (3);
\draw [line] (3) to  (6);
\draw [line] (5) to  (7);
\draw [line] (8) to  (6);
\draw [line] (7) to  (9);
\draw [line] (8) to  (10);
\draw [line] (9) to  (10);
\draw [line] (7) to  (6);
\draw [line] (9) to  (8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The same output could be easily obtained with a significantly shorter code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[ball/.style={circle, draw, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.2em}]
\draw [line width=0.625] (0,0) grid (3,1);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
  \path (\x,0) node [ball](\x0){} (\x,1) node [ball](\x1){};
\path (-1,.5) node[ball](left){} (4,.5) node[ball](right){};
\draw [line width=0.625] (left)--(00) (left)--(01) (right)--(30) (right)--(31);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I take "freedom" to extend my comment to answer. For demonstration purposes I white colored node contents that can be visible (I wonder why you put numbers in node if you then cover with black fill?) and in the same time make your MWE more concise:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=12.5 pt and 24pt,
    every node/.style={draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt},
                       minimum size=2.7ex, text=white]

\node (1)                       {1};
\node (2) [above right=of 1]    {2};
\node (3) [right=of 2]          {3};
\node (4) [below=of 1-| 2]      {4};
\node (5) [below=of 1-| 3]      {5};
\node (6) [right=of 3]          {6};
\node (7) [below=of 1-| 6]      {7};
\node (8) [right=of 6]          {8};
\node (9) [below=of 1-| 8]      {9};
\node (10)[below right=of 8]    {10};
\draw [line width=0.625pt]  (1) to  (2)
                            (1) to  (4)
                            (4) to  (5)
                            (2) to  (3)
                            (4) to  (2)
                            (5) to  (3)
                            (3) to  (6)
                            (5) to  (7)
                            (8) to  (6)
                            (7) to  (9)
                            (8) to  (10)
                            (9) to  (10)
                            (7) to  (6)
                            (9) to  (8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

in preamble you need to add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`. This code generate the following image:

[image]